# restore large databases in mysql via phpmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

i already save a backup for all databases in phpmyadmin by about **4.5 MB** and **gzip** format.

but now i want to restore that in **phpmyAdmin** via import tab. but we know that max allowed size for upload a file is  2,048KiB and when try to upload shown this message error:

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration

i use  [MySQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net) script to restore but in this script we can choose only one database to restore while i want to restore all my databases that i had.

how can i do this. i use wamp on windows 8.

Comment: Why can't you increase the upload size in PHP?

Comment: go to php.ini and increase the sizes (`post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize`) reboot the server and try again

Comment: 4.5 MB is certainly not what most would consider a large database, but maybe rather a small real-world application database.  Once you need to start dealing with real world applications, you will need to know how to start using the `mysql` and `mysqldump` command line tools. See @Stegrex's answer below.

Comment: @MikeBrant Agreed. At work, doing a weekly dump and restore of up to 1 gigabyte DB dumps for development is pretty common, and there's just about no way to deal with it using phpmyadmin.

Comment: yes.i increase the sizes  (post_max_size, upload_max_filesize) and my file is uploaded. but when run sql file and error accured that said you cannot CREATE DATABASE  `information_schema`.by this error only some databases is restored. what do i do now for other databases.

Comment: @Ahmad You should not be dumping/restoring mysql or information_schema databases.  You should probably be using `mysqldump` command line tool.  It's default settings are pretty good for most use cases. Usage to dump all DB's would be `mysqldump --all-databases > dumpfile.sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore large database using mysqldumper http://www.mysqldumper.net. If you want to restore it on your domain server first you upload sql file using ftp and then restore using mysqldumper

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass having to use phpmyadmin by using the terminal.

You should unzip your mysqldump first.

Get the DOS command prompt by typing "cmd" under Start->Search programs and files.

Navigate to the directory where your mysqldump is, and then type (for single database):

mysql -u`username` -p`password` `name of database` < `filename of the mysqldump`

If you want to restore all the databases (it seems like you dumped using --all-databases):

mysql -u`username` -p`password` --databases `name of database` `name of another database` `name of yet another database` < `filename of the mysqldump`

Also note that there is no space in between -u and the username, and -p and the password.

Comment: thanks.what do i insert instead of "name of database" option while i do not have any databases and i want to restore all databases.

Comment: of course when run this command i recieve this error :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u newuser -p 123456 < localhost.sql' at line 1

Comment: @Ahmad I've edited my answer to cover the case that your dump is an all databases dump.

Comment: If you need to restore a database that already exists, you'll need to use mysqlimport command. The syntax for mysqlimport is as follows:

mysqlimport -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] [backupfile.sql]